# Proving basic properties of Hausdorff dimension and measure

Tags: measure-theory, fractals

I have two questions on basic properties of the Hausdorff measure and dimension which I've taken for granted for a while (I'm revisiting Falconer after about a year), but that I've never actually seen shown.

Firstly, I've always seen the Hausdorff dimension defined as: $$\dim_{H}(F) = \inf \{ s \geq 0 : H^{s}(F) = 0 \} = \sup \{ s \geq 0 : H^{s}(F) = \infty \}$$ and been shown the graph of the measure going from $\infty$ to $0$ at a *critical point* $s$, but I've never actually seen the proof that these two values actually coincide, i.e. that this graph is correct.

Also, I've never actually seen it shown that the Hausdorff measure is countably additive on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra under disjoint union (at least on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$), i.e. that it is indeed a measure.

If anybody could demonstrate these to me, or point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: For the dimension: Show that $\bigl(H^s(F) < \infty\bigr) \implies \Bigl(\bigl(\forall t > s\bigr)\bigl(H^t(F) = 0\bigr)\Bigr)$ and $\bigl(H^s(F) > 0\bigr) \implies \Bigl(\bigl(\forall r < s\bigr)\bigl(H^r(F) = +\infty\bigr)\Bigr)$. That implies the equality of the infimum and supremum in the definition of the dimension.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Thanks. And the part about $H^{s}$ being an honest-to-God measure?

Comment: @AJY The purpose of an edit is to clarify, correct, or otherwise *improve* a question - *not* to change it's content. Your edit deleted one question entirely, thus making Daniel's comment superfluous.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thanks for the information and fixing it back up.

Comment: If you want to see all the details, you should probably read a book -- such as *Measure theory and fine properties of functions* by Evans and Gariepy.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Hausdorff measure is a Borel measure follows fairly easily from the fact that it is a *metric outer measure*, i.e.
$${\cal H}^s(A \cup B) = {\cal H}^s(A) + {\cal H}^s(B),$$
whenever 
$$\inf_{a\in A,b\in B} \text{dist}(a,b)>0.$$
I think the fact that ${\cal H}^s$ is a metric outer measure is fairly easy to prove from the definition.  After all,
$${\cal H}^s(E) = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} {\cal H}^s_{\varepsilon}(E)$$
and the equality should hold for small enough $\varepsilon$.  From here, it's not hard to see that ${\cal H}^s$ should be additive on closed sets, from which it follows that it should be additive on Borel sets.  The details must certainly be worked out in the classic text [*Hausdorff Measures* by C. A. Rogers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521624916).

Comment: I'm aware that you can make Banach spaces where it's not a measure, e.g. $\ell^{p}$ spaces. I was more interested in the case of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ or $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, which are the only situations I know of where we actually give Hausdorff measure serious consideration.

Comment: @AJY What? My counter example is stated on the line - i.e. $\mathbb R^1$. The salient point is that countable additivity must be with respect to some $\sigma$-algebra. The answer itself is certainly applicable on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: My apologies. I should've specified that I was only concerned with the Hausdorff measure defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @AJY Again, my answer addresses exactly that.

Comment: My apologies; I seem to have misread a part and misunderstood your answer. I don't, however, see how what you wrote demonstrates countable additivity on closed sets.

Comment: @AJY I'm not claiming a complete answer - just the idea and a reference, as you asked for.  I suppose the key issue to address your present question is this: if you have disjoint closed sets (and they are bounded), then the they will be positively separated.